# Incorrect configuration for date

Tags: java

I use this code to execute Job in fixes time.

```
private static final ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
private static final ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *")
public void PaymentTransactionsDailyFactsScheduler() throws Exception { 
    .......

    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy  hh:mm a");
    String time = zonedDateTime.format(format);

    System.out.printf("Job Scheduler executed (%s, (%s))\n", time, zone);
}
```

But every time I get `Job Scheduler executed (Apr 13 2019  03:41 PM, (Europe/Germany))`

Do you know why the time is every time exactly the same? Probably I need to remove final?

Comment: Of course, since you create a single ZonedDateTime object, once and only once, when your class is being initialized. If you want the current time, create it **inside** the method.

Answer (score 1):

You create a single `ZonedDateTime` object, once and only once, when your class is being initialized.

If you want the *current* time of the execution of the method, create it **inside** the method.

Comment: Can you show me code example with optimized code solution please?

Comment: No. You should be able to move the variable declaration and initialization from the class to the method by yourself. It's not about being "optimized". it's about being "correct".